# Python store mp3 file as data in array

Tags: python, arrays, audio, mp3, tensorflow

I'm looking for a module that will read in an mp3 file (which is a binary file from what I understand) and store it's data values in an array. I'm new to the audio world, so I'm not sure what the values represent. Frequency maybe?

I'm working in a Tensorflow project that learns from an audio Byte stream. So I need some sort of way to represent an audio Byte stream.

A standard `read()` might work, but each audio file needs to be represented as an entire array. So maybe each element represents a frame of the audio stream.

I found this [link](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/10/04/read-and-write-audio-files-in-python-using-ffmpeg/), but I can't get it to work.

I have:

```
     command = [FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-i', image_file,
            # '-f', 's16le',
            # '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
            '-ar', '44100',
            '-ac', '2']
        # pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
      pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE)
      raw_audio = pipe.proc.stdout.read(88200*4)
```

But it's throwing an error: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Note that `image_file` is a path to the file --> `train/rock/006 - The Doors - Light My Fire.mp3`

The entire snippet looks like this:

```
for image_index, image in enumerate(image_files):
  image_file = os.path.join(folder, image)
  try:
    command = [FFMPEG_BIN,
        '-i', image_file,
        # '-f', 's16le',
        # '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
        '-ar', '44100',
        '-ac', '2']
    # pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
    pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE)
    raw_audio = pipe.proc.stdout.read(88200*4)

  except IOError as e:
   print('Could not read:', image_file, ':', e, '- it\'s ok, skipping.')
```

Comment: Can you add in the part where you assign `image_file` to that path?  Maybe something's not correct there.

Comment: ...and just to complete my Devil's Advocate position, do you get any errors opening the file normally, right after `image_file =...` ?

Comment: @Gerrat nope, I was previously using a read method successfully, but it was for images. No problem there. The path is correct.

Comment: @Gerrat problem solved --> brew install ffmpeg